# Gesture Zoom and Pan in a VCL Windows application

Tags: zooming, c++builder, gesture, vcl, pan

I'm trying to zoom and pan an image (TImage) with an object (TShape) on it in a VCL Windows application running on an all-in-one pc with touch display.

I put the image in a panel (TPanel) so when I zoom it, it remains always inside the panel.
Then I put a shape (TShape) on the image.

What I would like to get is to zoom and pan the image and the shape should zoom and move with the image.

I started from the Embarcadero sample "Mobile Snippets - InteractiveGestures - ImageZoom" and with the following code I managed to do image zoom and pan with two fingers:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Image1Gesture(TObject *Sender, const TGestureEventInfo &EventInfo,  bool &Handled)  {

TPointF LImageCenter;
double expance;
TPointF movement;

try {

    if (EventInfo.GestureID == static_cast<short>(Vcl::Controls::igiZoom)) {
        if (!EventInfo.Flags.Contains(TInteractiveGestureFlag::gfBegin) &&
                !EventInfo.Flags.Contains(TInteractiveGestureFlag::gfEnd)) {
            // zoom the image
            TImage * LImage = dynamic_cast<TImage*>(Image1);
            LImageCenter.x = LImage->Left + (LImage->Width / 2);
            LImageCenter.y = LImage->Top + (LImage->Height / 2);
            expance = EventInfo.Distance - FLastDistance;
            if (((LImage->Width + (expance * AR))> MIN_DIM) &&
                    ((LImage->Height + (expance))> MIN_DIM)) {

                LImage->Width = (int)(LImage->Width + (expance * AR));
                LImage->Height = (int)(LImage->Width / AR );
            }

            LImage->Left = LImageCenter.X - LImage->Width / 2;
            LImage->Top = LImageCenter.Y - LImage->Height / 2;
        }
        FLastDistance = EventInfo.Distance;
    }

    else if (EventInfo.GestureID == static_cast<short>(Vcl::Controls::igiPan)) {
        if (!EventInfo.Flags.Contains(TInteractiveGestureFlag::gfBegin) &&
                !EventInfo.Flags.Contains(TInteractiveGestureFlag::gfEnd)) {

            // move the image
            TImage * LImage = dynamic_cast<TImage*>(Image1);
            movement.x = EventInfo.Location.X - FLastLocation.x;
            movement.y = EventInfo.Location.Y - FLastLocation.y;

            LImage->Left += movement.x;
            LImage->Top += movement.y;
        }
        FLastLocation.x = EventInfo.Location.X;
        FLastLocation.y = EventInfo.Location.Y;
    }

} catch (Exception &e) {
    ShowMessage(e.Message);
}  }
```

`AR` is the image aspect ratio and `MIN_DIM` is a define to set the minimum image dimensions for the zoom.

The pan movement is not so great...

I don't know how to make the shape to behave in accordance with the image zoom and move.

The shape parent is the panel under the image, not the image, so the shape is completely independent from the image changes.

I can't set the image as the shape parent.

Whatever suggestion to get the desired result will be appreciated.

The pan movement is not smooth because `EventInfo.Location.X` and `EventInfo.Location.Y` do not vary in a smooth way.
If I start the pan movement and I stop, even if fingers are still `EventInfo.Location` continues to change.

Is there a way to avoid this behavior?

Comment: @Tomerikoo. Hi Tomerikoo, I'd like to know why you edited my post. Yes, I made a mistake writing "behavior" and I thank you for your correction but why other changes? My post was not understandable? I violated rules? It is a bad thing to thanks in advance for future possible answers? When I edited the post to add a second question, I wanted to separate the two questions, it is a bad thing? So, why?

Comment: I initially edited the post to fix the misuse of the `zoom-sdk` tag. This tag is for the video app Zoom, not zooming images. Then, I just fixed some small stuff. Regarding your other question, Stack Overflow questions should really be focused on one question and asking multiple questions in one can lead to your question being closed as too broad. I tried to help you avoid that by *disguising* the multiple questions